# Stacking Ensenble Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, ensemble-learning

I have some pre trained models and i would like to Stack them together. my input is a (224,224,3) image, something like 1000 images. and my y is a (1000,2) shape, something like ([0,1],[1,0],[0,1]...[1,0]). Here is the CNNs

```
base_Neural_Net=MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
Mobile_V2=Sequential()
Mobile_V2.add(base_Neural_Net)
Mobile_V2.add(Flatten())
Mobile_V2.add(BatchNormalization())
Mobile_V2.add(Dense(256,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
Mobile_V2.add(BatchNormalization())
Mobile_V2.add(Activation('relu'))
Mobile_V2.add(Dropout(0.5))
Mobile_V2.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

for layer in base_Neural_Net.layers:
layer.trainable = False

c1=PlotLossesKeras()
Mobile_V2.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy','AUC'])
Mobile_V2.fit(x,y,epochs=10,callbacks=[c1,c3],batch_size=10)

base_Neural_Net=DenseNet121(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
Dense_121=Sequential()
Dense_121.add(base_Neural_Net)
Dense_121.add(Flatten())
Dense_121.add(BatchNormalization())
Dense_121.add(Dense(256,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
Dense_121.add(BatchNormalization())
Dense_121.add(Activation('relu'))
Dense_121.add(Dropout(0.5))
Dense_121.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

for layer in base_Neural_Net.layers:
layer.trainable = False

c1=PlotLossesKeras()
Dense_121.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy','AUC'])
Dense_121.fit(x,y,epochs=10,callbacks=[c1,c3],batch_size=16)

base_Neural_Net= InceptionResNetV2(input_shape= (224,224,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
Res_V2=Sequential()
Res_V2.add(base_Neural_Net)
Res_V2.add(Flatten())
Res_V2.add(BatchNormalization())
Res_V2.add(Dense(256,kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
Res_V2.add(BatchNormalization())
Res_V2.add(Activation('relu'))
Res_V2.add(Dropout(0.5))
Res_V2.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

for layer in base_Neural_Net.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

c1=PlotLossesKeras()
Res_V2.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy','AUC'])
Res_V2.fit(x,y,epochs=10,callbacks=[c1,c3],batch_size=16)

estimators_model = [
('Mobile_V2', Mobile_V2),
('Res_V2', Res_V2),
('Dense_121', Dense_121)
]
```

How can i ensenble them ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use models in an ensemble is just to run them separately on your data and collect the outputs from each, then average the totals. If you want your results to be the discrete values {0, 1} you can just convert based on a threshold.

You can also build a combined network to do this, but that's more involved. You'd need to use the Keras functional api to build a new model with these as components, each taking the same input. You'd then average the outputs in the combined model, and transform as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

agree with @dennis-sosnoski, also if you want to train an ensemble of CNN simultaneously then you can simply create a multi-input model, where each input pipeline consists of a unique CNN model and at the end you need to join them and give a single prediction. I did something similar to this a year ago, see the image below,

Click [Here](https://github.com/greatsharma/Facial_Emotion_Recognition/blob/d77873cfcc8f034803f280ce654c160773ce71b6/models.py#L330) to see the code as well.

[image]